# How to find and operate child controls?CheckBox in ComboBox

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a TemplatedControl Combobox.
axaml file

```
<Styles xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:TempCon.ViewModels"
        xmlns:controls="using:TempCon">
    <Design.PreviewWith>
        <controls:MultiSelectComboBox />
    </Design.PreviewWith>

    <Style Selector="controls|MultiSelectComboBox">
        <!-- Set Defaults -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ComboBox  Name="tempComboBox"   ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Datas}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox  Content="{Binding VersionName}"  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    
                </ComboBox>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Styles>
```

axaml.cs

```
namespace TempCon
{
    public partial class MultiSelectComboBox : TemplatedControl
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Datas DirectProperty definition
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DirectProperty<MultiSelectComboBox, IEnumerable?> DatasProperty =
            AvaloniaProperty.RegisterDirect<MultiSelectComboBox, IEnumerable?>(nameof(Datas),
                o => o.Datas,
                (o, v) => o.Datas = v);

        private IEnumerable? _Datas;//= new ObservableCollection<VersionInfo>();
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Datas  property. This DirectProperty 
        /// indicates ....
        /// </summary>
        public IEnumerable? Datas
        {
            get => _Datas;
            set
         {
                SetAndRaise(DatasProperty, ref _Datas, value);
            }
        }

        public MultiSelectComboBox()
        {

        }

        public override void Render(DrawingContext context)
        {
            base.Render(context);

            CheckBox selectedAllCheckBox = new CheckBox();
            selectedAllCheckBox.Content = "Select All";
            selectedAllCheckBox.IsChecked = false;

            var controls = this.GetTemplateChildren();
            var box = (ComboBox)controls.First();
        }

        
    }
}
```

Parent axaml file:

```
<UserControl xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TempCon.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
         xmlns:tc="using:TempCon"
             x:Class="TempCon.Views.MainView"
             x:DataType="vm:MainViewModel">
  <Design.DataContext>
    <!-- This only sets the DataContext for the previewer in an IDE,
         to set the actual DataContext for runtime, set the DataContext property in code (look at App.axaml.cs) -->
    <vm:MainViewModel />
  </Design.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Greeting}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <tc:MultiSelectComboBox  Datas="{Binding Versions}"></tc:MultiSelectComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**I would like to add a select all option, where when clicking on select all, all sub items are selected,But I don't know how to dynamically add [Select All] Checkbox and add some events to it**

How to add *selectedAllCheckBox  *to *box *

[image]

use box.ItemTemplate to operate?